# Install php5 instead of the default php7.0 with the LAMP stack

Tags: 16.04, php, lamp, php7

I'm installing the LAMP stack this way:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

On **Ubuntu 16.04 it installs php7.0**

Is it possible to make it install the exact same thing but with **php5 instead of php7** (as it was done in previous versions of Ubuntu)?

Comment: As per Justin L. Franks' answer below, yes you can. However, unless you need continued support for deprecated features (e.g. on an in-house server for legacy applications) you really should ask yourself whether this is the way to go. If you have PHP code that no longer runs on PHP7, that means the features that this code relies on were removed from PHP for good reasons. Keeping old code running like that on public-facing servers has limited prospects. Rather spend your time updating your code to run on PHP7.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ondřej Surý's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php).

This will allow you to install any combination of PHP 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, and 7.2 alongside each other.

To install:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
    sudo apt update
```

PHP 5.6 package names will begin with php5.6-, PHP 7.0 package names will begin with php7.0-, and so forth.

For information on running multiple PHP versions using this PPA, see [this page in the wiki](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/wiki/Managing-Multiple-Versions).